# Checking connection between server and client without sending multiple packet every second

Tags: tcp, server, client, monitoring, ping

as stated above, im trying to checking connection between server and client, without using ping, or some packet that will send every second.

i already try ping method, but this method will cause flooding, and i already try tcp method that act like icmp, the tcp packet will send tcp packet every second, to make sure the connection betweet sever and client still on, but this doesnt solve the flooding problem.

do you guys have any idea how to do this, without causing flooding?

all i need is server only send like 3 way handshake, and the connection built, and when the client off, something will trigger the server, and tell that server that, this client in particular are offline.

in simple, how to monitor client and server connectoin without sending multiple packet?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Say some link halfway between the client and server stops passing traffic. It may or may not still be possible for the client and server to communicate, depending on whether there are alternate links. But there is no way to tell whether or not that communication is possible without doing something active. There is no passive way to tell whether or not a link failure has made a connection usable or unusable.

There is, in general, no easier or more efficient way to tell whether or not communication is possible than attempting that communication and seeing whether or not it works.